# How to get NServiceBUS performance counter to work?

Tags: nservicebus

I've setup NServiceBus to run in a production profile. I've also executed the `runner.exe` which "reinstalls" the performance counter "critical time" under NServicebus. But when I run my application and tries to enable the counter in perfmon, I get an "no instance" under the NServicebus critical timer. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by using the `NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters` profile when installing my service.  If you use the `NServiceBus.Production` profile, it does not set up the counter.  To get the behaviour of both, pass both profiles along on the install(http://nservicebus.com/Profiles.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick for me and the project. I haven´t found a good overview of all the NSB features, do you know one?

Comment: What level of granularity are you looking for?

Comment: Well some kind of API description, like which profiles exixts snd so on. Until now I have just used the website

Comment: I have this link for the API: http://www.nservicebus.com/Documentation/Documentation.pdf  Not sure how current it is though.  Beyond the site and the API doc, I don't think there is something at that level of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up perfmon after the NServiceBus process is already running otherwise it doesn't pick up the instance.

Comment: No luck so far. Tried to close everything running. Started the runner.exe to reinstall the performancecounter, went ok. Startet my program using nservicebus.host.exe nservicebus.production. After a while I started perfmon, found the counter NServiceBus.CriticalTime, but no instance.

Comment: Hi today I tested on both Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003. The counter shows up in Perfmon, but no instances exists.....